# How to get an export option as a pdf for views?

Tags: views, files

I am using views on my Drupal site I can able to export my view in csv, but I am not able export my views as pdf I need to export my view as pdf. Any suggestions on this it will be very helpful, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Views Pdf module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_pdf)

**Description of viewspdf module:**

> With this module you can output a view as a PDF document. Each field of the view can be placed on the PDF page directly in the
> administration interface. Therefore a new display called "PDF" is
> added.
>
> There are already some PDF solutions such as Print. But these solutions use the HTML output and converts this to PDF. The downsides
> of such an integration are:
>
> No control over page flow (e.g. page break).
> Little or no control over page header and footer.
> You need HTML skills to change the layout.
> The rendering is slow and need a lot of memory, because it needs to render the HTML.
> Complex tables make troubles.
> Vector graphics can not be implemented, therefore the printing of the document can be problematic.
> You are limited by HTML's capabilities.
> No hyphenation.
>
> You can also specify a background PDF document. This enables you to put unlimited static content to the dynamic PDF. This static PDF
> can be exchanged dynamically by using a File Field. The PDF can be
> created by any PDF creator such as Adobe Acrobat Professional or Open
> Office.

Comment: @ Zhilevan-Thanks for your response i will check with this and get back to you..

Comment: @DINE did you try that?

Comment: This module can also work in Drupal 10.